# Skype can't connect with mobile broadband internet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, skype, broadband

I now use a mobile broadband key to connect to the internet. I had to manually configure it to work, and all internet apps (firefox, Kmess, etc), work well. Except for Skype. When I try to log in, it thinks for 5 minutes before saying "connection error". I run Ubuntu 12.04, and Skype was downloaded from the Software Centre. Skype still signs in when I have a wifi or wired internet connection.
Any suggestions?? 
PS, I'm not very good with the terminal app!

Answer (score 1):

You should google around and see if your ISP is blocking Skype.

In Ireland where I am, a number of networks did this when they first started selling 3G handsets to try to protect their call revenue stream.

If you post your network provider and country, it might be possible to assist in finding more info.

One network provider I'm aware of blocked Viber, Whatsapp and Skype until enough business users complained then they were unblocked for bill pay customers but if you were on a pay as you go phone (top up as you use it) then they still blocked it until eventually they gave up on that too because their competitors started allowing these services and they had to enable it for competition reasons.

But here it sounds like everything is working fine with your connection and I would suggest, it is your mobile broadband provider that is causing the problem one way or another.  If you ring and ask they will most likely deny it.  Your best bet is to see if other users of the same network and reporting similar issues online.

source for ISP's blocking VOIP services:
http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2056591510

Comment: I have the same problem, and my ISP is not blocking skype. I'm using a build-in wireless broadband modem (in my thinkpad), and I suspect there are something either in skype or in ubuntu that sees this connection as 'metered' and blocks it.
When I connect via wifi shared by my phone (same ISP), it works.

Answer (score -2):

Go to This link For solution Read Article 
http://blastsoftwares.blogspot.com/2014/02/cant-connect-check-network-settings.html